# How to know the Android Webview version or WkWebView version of the device on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, wkwebview

I am using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package and I want to log the users' device info for the system Webview version for Android and WkWebView for iOS how can I get the corresponding webview version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package [fk_user_agent](https://pub.dev/packages/fk_user_agent) can retrieve user agent which includes info about the web view version

```
await FkUserAgent.init();
String? userAgent = FkUserAgent.webViewUserAgent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get the `WkWebView` version from the **user agent string** by looking for the string "AppleWebKit/"?

For example:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
let userAgent = webView.value(forKey: "applicationNameForUserAgent") as? String
var webViewVersion: String?

if let userAgent = userAgent, let range = userAgent.range(of: "AppleWebKit/") {
    let startIndex = range.upperBound
    webViewVersion = String(userAgent[startIndex...])
}

print("WkWebView version: \(webViewVersion ?? "unknown")")
```

Comment: This is native code I was searching for a direct way in Flutter but thanks I found a package in Flutter that retrieves user agent